# msacces 2010 how to create table with comboboxes in subtable from many related tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, related-content

I have the tables:
products, measures, colors
for each product I have related measures and colors.
Also I have a form with subtable where I need to show the table with columns:
[products] comboboxColumn, [measures] comboboxColumn and [colors] comboboxColumn.
The rows should be selected product, selected measure, selected color.

The question is:
how can I filter the measures ComboBox list for [measures] combobox-Cell (or colors ComboBox list) in my grid selected row, when I choosing a product from [products] combobox-Cell in that very selected row?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pz8a.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qDpzZ.png]

Comment: Thanks HansUp the stackoverflow doesn't allow me to add an image in my question

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use a continuous form rather than a datasheet. Create the combo and populate it with the relevant values in the current event and bind it to the correct field in your table. To avoid confusing the user, include a textbox bound to that field also. You can lock the textbox and label the combobox column something like "Choose Size". You can use conditional formatting to make the whole think prettier.